# Need a data set for fraud detection

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, outliers, fraud-prevention

I have a fraud detection algorithm, and I want to check to see if it works against a real world data set.

My algorithm says that a claim is usual or not.

Are there any data sets available?

Comment: A new dataset for credit card fraud is available in https://www.kaggle.com/dalpozz/creditcardfraud

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Below are some datasets I found that might be related.

#### Credit fraud

- [German credit fraud](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/file/n23121/credit_fruad.arff) dataset: in weka's `arff` format

#### Email fraud

- [Enron dataset](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/)

#### Credit Approval

- [German credit](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Statlog+%28German+Credit+Data%29) dataset@ UCI
- [Australian credit approval](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Statlog+%28Australian+Credit+Approval%29)

#### Intrusion Dectection

- [Intrusion Detection](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/databases/kddcup99/) kddcup99 dataset

Answer (score 3):

I believe the KDD Cup is dedicated to that type of task. They have some dataset that are freely available and are usually used in various fraud detection papers.

Check out [KDD Cup DataSets](http://www.sigkdd.org/kddcup/index.php)